# Git post-receive hook for the repository and finding out which submodule is pushed

Tags: git, git-submodules, githooks

I have a main module in my application (say Module A) and a lot of sub-modules for it (say B,C and D). I need to create a post-receive hook for the main module (which is easy to do) but will it be invoked when any of its sub-modules are pushed? If yes, how do I find which sub-module is pushed ?

I need to know the sub-module name as I need to trigger a Jenkins build for whichever module that has been pushed. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> will it be invoked when any of its sub-modules are pushed?

No, it will not.

But nothing prevents you to add post-receive hooks on the submodules, each one of them can in turn call directly the post-receive hook of the parent repo (if it exists: `../../../hooks/post-receive`, since a submodule hook is in `parent_repo/.git/modules/asubmodules/hooks`).
It can call the parent repo hook with its own name as argument, for the parent hook to:

- detect that it isn't called in a classic way, but through one of its submodule repos.
- trigger the right builds.

Comment: Sounds good. But how can the parent hook can go a git status without a valid git repo. ?

Comment: @KarthikJ Right. I have amended the answer accordingly.